# Issue with Materialize and Boostrap in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

So I already have Bootstrap installed in my Rails app and I used materialize gem for Rails in order to add some materialize components to my app. Actually I only want to add materialize form and button components.

However, when I include:

```
 @import "materialize";
```

along with materialize components,in my application.scss file, some bootstrap components now just disappear from a page.

This is my application.scss file:

```
// These both need to be imported before bootstrap:
@import 'globals/fonts';
@import 'globals/variables';


// --------------Bootstrap-----------------------------
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';


// --------------Global definitions--------------------
// For example (add your own!!):
@import 'globals/mixins';


// --------------Shared styles-------------------------
// Common base CSS modifications. For example:
@import 'shared/buttons';
@import 'shared/grid';


// --------------Components----------------------------
// Create your own and modify/extend Bootstrap's. For example:
@import 'components/panel';


// --------------Sections------------------------------
// Page-specific styles. These should *only* be used as a last
// resort if you really truly can't style your content more generally.
@import 'sections/profile_page';
@import "materialize";
```

My guess is that materialize is turning every code to his compenents... Is it possible to somehow stop materialize from converting bootstrap components for certain elements(or pages)?